# Misuse of Tangent Vector

Tags: differential-geometry, self-learning

I am quite confused with the term **tangent** used in differential geometry books. It seems to me that people use this word quite loosely. For example, one definition about tangent space in my book is as follows.

The tangent space $T_p(\mathbb R^n)$ at $p\in\mathbb R^n$ is the vector space of all arrows emanating from $p$.

If this is the case, then the tangent space at $p$ can be a vector pointing to any direction. However, intuitively a tangent vector is only meaningful with respect to some kind of geometric object such as a surface or curve where the tangent vector at a point is the vector that only touch the surface or curve at point $p$ if it is extended to a plane or line. **My question is how to interpret the word tangent in differential geometry. Is it still consistent with the geometric intuition I have from curve and surfaces, please? Thank you!**

Comment: Most books I know give a much more rigorous definition of the tangent space than this. What book are you using?

Comment: The geometric object for your intuition is $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself. The application $\mathbb{R}^n \ni v \mapsto p + v \in T_p (\mathbb{R}^n)$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you define the tangent space to a point $p\in \mathbb R^n$ as the set $$T_p\mathbb R^n=\{(p, v): v\in \mathbb R^n\}=\{p\}\times \mathbb R^n.$$ Notice you may think as the tangent space to $\mathbb R^n$ at $p$ as a copy of $\mathbb R^n$ lying on $p$. Each $T_p\mathbb R^n$ is a vector space with the operations: $$\alpha (p, u)+(p, v)=(p, \alpha u+v).$$

With this it is clear $\{(e_1, p), \ldots, (e_n, p)\}$ is a basis for every $T_p\mathbb R^n$ so $T_p\mathbb R^n\simeq \mathbb R^n$ for each $p\in\mathbb R^n$.

**Important:** If $p\neq q$ you **can't** operate $v_p\in T_p\mathbb R^n$ with $v_q\in T_q\mathbb R^n$ for it wouldn't yield a well defined operation.

Now let us consider the tangent space to a surface embedded in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $M\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a surface. We say $v\in \mathbb R^n$ is a tangent vector to $M$ at $p\in M$ if there exists a differentiable curve $$\gamma:(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)\longrightarrow M$$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma^{'}(0)=v$. Again $T_pM$ denotes the set of all tangent vector to $p\in M$.

This above definition agrees with our intuition.

**Obs:** Again you can show $T_pM$ is a vector space with the natural operations isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{\textrm{dim}(M)}$.

**Exercise:** Show that $T_pS^n=\{v\in \mathbb R^n: \langle v, p\rangle=0\}$ (as expected).

Comment: Do we have the same $\mathbb R^n$ at each point $p$ or different $\mathbb R^n$ at different $p$? Or maybe I can say $\mathbb R^n$ is the same at each point $p$. However, $p$ is different. Therefore, $T_p\mathbb R^n$ is not the same as $T_q\mathbb R^n$ even though they share the same $\mathbb R^n$. Is this right, please?

Comment: Observation: since $ p \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the correct definition would be $\gamma (0) = p $ and $\gamma ' (0) = v$.

Comment: @20824: they are isomorphic but not identical, because the base points are different, as you say. the structure here is really that of a "vector bundle."

Comment: @symplectomorphic That makes more sense now. Thank you.